# What is the regex to match a single element in a group of almost equivalent elements?

Tags: regex

In the following content:

```
<page1 ...>
   ...
</page>

<page2 ...>
   ...
</page>

<page3 ...>
   ...
   <queue>...</queue>
   ...
</page>
```

How do you find the match just for the very last element (the one that contains the queue tag)?

I have tried

```
(?s)<page.*?<queue>.*?</page>
```

But that matches the ENTIRE content.  I've been trying to play around with lookaheads, but can't figure it out.

Comment: is it well-formed xml? why pick regex?

Comment: Eclipse IDE regex?  I'm picking regex because I have to do a mass find-replace on certain tags.  Plus, I want to learn more about regex.  Seems like a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following monster for your particular use case:

```python
<page(?:[^/]+/(?!page))+queue>(?:[^/]+|/(?!page))+/page>
```

..not sure if this is the best example for learning regex and definitely not a good idea to use to parse XML in real life. But it is possible. Don't forget to escape `/` by `\/` in languages that quote regular expressons inside `/.../` construct.

See technical explanation at http://regex101.com/r/qZ0yR1/2.

The logic is following:

1. `<page.../queue>.../page>` - get the content of a page element that contains end tag for queue
2. `[^/]+/(?!page)` - match all text up to the next closing tag, but make sure that it is not a closing tag for page
3. `(?:[^/]+/(?!page))+queue>` - repeat above match as many times as needed until the closing tag is for queue
4. `(?:[^/]+|/(?!page))+/page>` - then repeat as many times as needed until the closing tag is for page (I used `|` as a shortcut for `(?:[^/]+/(?!page))+[^/]+/page>`, because the expression in point 2. will only match the text if following closing tag is not for page, but we need to match exactly that text in the end)

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  It successfully returns matches all <page> tags with a <queue> tag in them.  Now to try and understand this monster :).

Comment: I added some high-level explanation, hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot.  I was confused by this part for a while: [^/]+/, but after working through it, it makes sense.  I feel like I've gained a level in regex.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you could use this pattern

```
(?:<page[^>]*>(?:(?!<queue>).)*?<\/page>)|(<page[^>]*>.*?<\/page>)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/133)

the idea here is to consume the tags that do not contain `queue` first then consume and capture the ones that does.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most succinct I could muster:

```
<page(.(?!page))*<queue.*<\/page>
```

You need the DOTALL flag set, and the whole match is your target.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/VKO8XgxTbk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a greedy match (.*) to match everything up to the last tag.

Here's an example (excuse the Java):

```
final String str = "<page1 foo='bar'>apple</page> <page2 foo='bar'>orange</page> <page3 foo='bar'>pear</page>";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*<page[^>]+>(\\w+)</page>$");
final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
matcher.find();

// Prints pear
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Also, +1 for 'why pick regex'; regex is not a good fit for this problem.

Comment: only if you set `.` to match newlines if there are newlines in the actual text

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tag might not be 'queue' and could be anything else, try the following:

`(?<=[>]).*(?=\<\/[\w]+\>([\n]?)(.*[\n])?\<\/page\>$)`

example here:

http://regex101.com/r/sN6aC5/1

This uses a look ahead to find the last closed tag `</...>` that is followed by anything and then a closed page tag `</page>` that is the end of the string. It then, using a lookbehind, matches everything between this final close tag and the first `>` before that (which should be the last opening tag)